# Ещё ошибка в node, как исправить

Tags: node.js

учусь по этому [скринкасту](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YZwAVRsa1O4&list=PLDyvV36pndZFWfEQpNixIHVvp191Hb3Gg&index=37) собствено как в скринкасте делаю

```
require('routes')(app);
```

вот так делаю в routes/index.js

```
module.esports = function (app) {...}
```

подключаю получаю ошибку

```
require('routes')(app);
                 ^
TypeError: require(...) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/chatnode/app.js:24:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

что опять не так?

Comment: Опечатка? `module.esports` -> `module.exports`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените на

```
const app = require('routes');
```

и исправьте опечатку `module.esports` на `module.exports`